# how to dynamically change title in Chart ,using apex:line series

Tags: charts

```
<apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="monthName" yField="property1" strokeColor="#itle="{!property }" />
<apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="monthName" yField="property2" strokeColor="#A845DC" strokeWidth="1"
         markerType="circle" markerSize="2" markerFill="#A845DC"    />
<apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="monthName" yField="property3" strokeColor="#006400" strokeWidth="1" 
         markerType="circle" markerSize="2" markerFill="#006400"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is **title** attribute in `lineseries` tag. You can bind a string with it and re-render as per your requirement. See example below:-

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:chart id="rerenderChart" height="400" width="700" data="{!data}">


    <apex:lineSeries title="{!MY_LINE_SERIES_title}" left" xField="name" yField="data1"
        fill="true" markerType="cross" markerSize="4" markerFill="#FF0000"/>


    <apex:lineSeries title="{!titleString}" left" xField="name" yField="data2"
        markerType="circle" markerSize="4" markerFill="#8E35EF"/>
</apex:chart>
```

Comment: can you please send that controller {!MY_LINE_SERIES_title}functionality?